# How to fix this JSON response? I do not control the API

Tags: android, json, rest, retrofit

I'm working on an Android application that presents information from a public REST API (using Retrofit). One call is to gather bonus text information about a certain object. The call looks like this:

`/text/1`

The response I get is this:

```
{"textObject":[
    {
        "id":1,
        "text":"{"More info" : {"url": "http://someurl.com/"}}"
    }
]}
```

The string prints to {"More info" : {"url": "http://someurl.com/"}}. I don't think that is what they intended. I guess they wanted to include some more tags but I don't know.

Another answer might look like this:

```
/text/2

{"textObject":[
    {
        "id":2,
        "text":"{" Placement":"The object is located on this spot"}"
    }
]}
```

And the string of course prints to {" Placement":"The object is located on this spot"}

```
/text/3

{"textObject":[
    {
        "id":3,
        "text":"{"Institutions":"Math, Computer Science, Informatics", "imageUrl": "http://www.someimageurl.com/img.jpg"}"
    }
]}

/text/4
{"textObject":[
]}
```

I have no idea how to fix this, is it even at all possible without contacting the ones controlling the API?

Comment: You could take the printed string and create another `JSONObject`. If that works properly then reinsert the `JSONObject` back into `"text"`(possibly)

Comment: Smart thinking. I will give it an hour then I'll give up.

Comment: Well, they are formatted differently. Example #1 gives {"url":"http://someurl.com/"} (another JSONObject) and #2 gives "The object is located on this spot" (ready for printing). I have no idea what other "versions" there may be. Any suggestions?

Comment: what happens if you call "text/3", and/or "text/4"? If they give more/different information, keep looping (text/5, text/6, etc.) until it returns a blank.

Comment: @JackBeNimble I've added 3 and 4 in the post.

Comment: What were the results?